# Bandwidth 'silverman' or 'scott' in sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity causes TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, bandwidth, kernel-density

I am using sklearn's KernelDensity Estimator on a simple series.

When I try to fit a KDE, I get the "TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'" if I use 'silverman' or 'scott' as bandwidth instead of a float.
From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html#sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity) I can see however that both 'silverman' and 'scott' are supported.

Any input is greatly appreciated :)

Below my code:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity

#a random Series that I want to fit a KDE on
X = pd.Series([0,1,1,4,5,8])

#reformat the Series
X = X.to_numpy().reshape(-1,1)

#fit KDE
kde = KernelDensity(kernel = 'epanechnikov', bandwidth = 'silverman').fit(X)
```

returns TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

If I use a float for the bandwith, everything works just fine.

Comment: What version of sklearn? It looks like the bandwidth estimation approaches were just added in 1.2, and before that a validation step included testing if `bandwidth <= 0`.

Comment: That was the issue! Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Updating sklearn to version 1.2 did the trick

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).